# Why did http request and backend service save string data type to database with double quotes?

Tags: spring-boot, http, controller

I am working on a web application. Backend: spring boot and frontend: vuejs.
When I test with Swagger, my controller that provide to save a string data to database work fine but save with double quotes. At the same time when I wrote my data from an input in vue js I face to face same mistake again. My data is in my database but with double quotes.
I hope I can explain my problem clearly.
I don't want to see "sample data" in database, it will be just sample data without double quotes.

```
@PatchMapping("addSampleName/{clmnId}")
@Override
public Result addSampleName(@PathVariable ("clmnId") int clmnId, @RequestBody String sampleName) 

{
    return this.columnTableService.addSampleName(clmnId, sampleName);
}
```

Comment: Add code as text, not as link to an image

Answer (score 0):

I found where I made mistake. @RequestBody had got directly String type. I changed my parameter's type to "Map<String, object>" and this fixed my problem. I add my new code block.

```
@PatchMapping("addSampleName/{clmnId}")
@Override
public Result addSampleName(@PathVariable ("clmnId") int clmnId, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) 
{
    
    return this.columnTableService.addSampleName(clmnId, data);
}
```

(Of course you should change your method that is in service and class that implemented this service.)